# Single Page from Photoshop Template

Tags: html, css, photoshop, psd

I am trying to make a single page from a psd file where the nav bar is fixed, and the background of each div is always full screen, the screenshot is http://2.s3.envato.com/files/50797146/01_preview01.jpg ANY HELP? :S

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 1):

*Why am I not allowed to comment ?*

Well this is not a we do it for free page. I think this question is off topic. If you have a direct question with a well descriped problem, edit your question to it.